# How to join two tables and get values in Yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-model

I'm using Yii2 **gridview widget** to display the data.

I'm using two tables named as **message** and **message_trigger**.

In **message** table columns are `object_model`, `Object_id`.

In **message_trigger** the column are `object_id`, `object_name`.

The grid get the values from the table **message**. So grid fields are `Object_model`, `Object_id`.

Now my problem is I need to show `Object_name` from the table `message_trigger` based on the `object_id` from the table **message**.

In my form I have used grid like this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'object_model',
        'object_id',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} '],
    ],
]); ?>
```

In model I have used

```
public function search($params){
    $query = AlertTrigger::find()->where(['alert_id'=>$params['id']])->andWhere(['!=','status',2]);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `Message` Model

```
public function getMessageTrigger()
{
    return $this->hasOne(MessageTrigger::className(), ['object_id' => 'object_id']);
}
```

in view

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'object_model',
        'object_id',
        [
            'label' => 'Name',
            'value' => 'messageTrigger.object_name',
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} '],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: What if I need to make the **object_name** sortable too??

Answer (score 4):

[ankitraturi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32409966/3049065) is the best answer. If anybody want to get value using a function from the model and use it in the gridview means follow the below steps.

1. Add the function which returning the value in the a model(Here I use `Message` Model).

> ```
> public static function get_message_trigger($id){
>     $model = MessageTrigger::find()->where(["object_id" => $id])->one();
>     if(!empty($model)){
>         return $model->object_name;
>     }
>
>     return null;
> }
> ```

2. In the Gridview use like below.

> ```
> <?= GridView::widget([
>     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
>     'filterModel' => $searchModel,
>     'columns' => [
>         ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
>         'object_model',
>         'object_id',
>         [
>             'label' => 'Name',
>             'value' => function($data){
>                 return Message::get_message_trigger($data->object_id)
>             },
>         ],
>         ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} '],
>     ],
> ]); ?>
> ```

Hope this will help someone.