# How to join two tables and get values in Yii2 gridview

Tags: yii2

Suppose I have two name then 
  How can I use the multiple value ?
    like:

```
 [
        'label' => 'Name',
        'value' => 'messageTrigger.object_name'.'messageTrigger.object_name2',
 ]
```

It is giving me error for Getting unknown property messageTrigger.object_name2

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166185/how-to-join-two-tables-and-get-values-in-yii2-gridview/33603225?noredirect=1#comment54983380_33603225) is reference link.

I have to do some modification on that but it giving me error 
    hope some one help me out for this

Solution:

```
   [
    'label' => 'Name',
    'value' => function ($data)               
    {$data->messageTrigger.object_name.$data->messageTrigger.object_name2}
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure:

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    /* @var $model YourModel */
    return $model->messageTrigger->object_name . $model->messageTrigger->object_name2;
},
```

It's better to wrap it in separate method in model, for example:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class MessageTrigger extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getFullObjectName()
    {
        return $this->object_name . $this->object_name2;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this and don't care about internal implementation:

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    /* @var $model YourModel */
    return $model->messageTrigger->getFullObjectName();
},
```

Or use a shortcut via getter:

```
'value' => 'messageTrigger.fullObjectName',
```

**P.S.** Make sure `messageTrigger` related model exists for every displayed model, otherwise add check for existence.